# Automate jitsi java application windows Desktop with pywinauto

Tags: voip, pywinauto, jitsi, inspect.exe

I am using jitsi windows Desktop for test voip service product.jitsi is a java windows application
I want automate jitsi for do it i use pywinauto is a python library for automate gui windows application and i use inspect.exe. but when i use inspect.exe for find Dialog and element i don’t see any thing that show buttom and any thing else. so i couldn’t automate jitsi yet and I would be thankful if you show me a possible path for automation.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWT apps can't be automated by pywinauto with text properties as you can see in `Inspect.exe`. Maybe it's worth looking into some Java tools like Jemmy.

This is the richest overview of Java tools I know of:
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18554/open-source-tools-for-automation-of-java-gui-application-testing

P.S. I'm not familiar with Java. So any specific Java question should be asked under "java" tag.